# After doing nn_send, the nn_socket will forbid to send the next piece of data immediately in a Req/Rep mode

Tags: c, zeromq, nanomsg

I'm using nanomsg to transfer pieces of my data from Windows to CentOS.

At the moment, I'm using **`Req/Rep`** mode.

The CentOS will send a `Req`-request, and "Windows" will respond with a `Rep` to it.

It looks alright.

But the pieces of data I respond to have mixed several structs. A data head following with several data frames.

I want to send them one by one.

But according to nanomsg, **`Req/Rep`** should just send a request, and receive a response one at a time. That's all.

So if I send the head, the **`nn_socket`** will forbid me to send the data frame.

What I can do is to make a big buffer, and cement the head and the data frames, and send them together.

Is there a way to send them one by one instead of sending together?

Thanks!

Comment: it seems should use nn_sendmsg........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like Google Protocol Buffers will be your friend here.

nanomsg sends complete messages. It's then simply a matter of what a "message" is. Essentially, it's just a set of bytes that it guarantees to deliver. It's up to you what those bytes actually represent.

This is where Google Protocol Buffers (or JSON, or XML, or ASN.1 [my personal favourite], and there's many others to choose from) comes in. It allows you to define message structures that meet your needs, and it then generates code that serialises and deserialises those messages. You write your code to serialise / deserialise to buffers (byte arrays, strings, whatever), which you pass as messages using nanomsg.

The nice thing is that you then don't have to worry about endianness, structure packing in different compilers, etc, or what programming language is being used at the other end, or whether the message in its deserialised form is contiguous in memory.

I mention GPB because it is free, fairly straightforward

Comment: As I have commented, we could use nn_sendmsg to resolve my situation. And it seems alright.  And I know a little about Google Protocol Buffers, thanks~~

Comment: @norikoSD nn_sendmsg will do it, but if you have a complex hierarchy of structures you'd be writing something like a deep-copy. That can be a lot of work, has to be done correctly everywhere the messages are sent and received, and has to be re-done every time you want to change the structure composition. And a mistake made in just one place can cause havoc. And you still have to worry about differences in structure packing in GCC and, presumably, MSC. Personally speaking I'm lazy, so I prefer to use something like GPB that allows me to avoid having to do that myself, and is more flexible too.

Comment: @norikoSD, if you want something faster than GPB, you could try Capn Proto https://capnproto.org/. This endeavours to have naturally laid out structures in one's program that are simply byte copied rather than serialised, but looks after the layout differences between different platforms. It could be a good compromise between a full on serialiser like GPB and raw structures.